# Numpy find identical element in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array `a` and `b`, how can I find the identical element in both arrays?

```
a = np.array([[262.5, 262.5, 45],
              [262.5, 262.5, 15],
              [262.5, 187.5, 45],
              [262.5, 187.5, 15],
              [187.5, 262.5, 45],
              [187.5, 262.5, 15],
              [187.5, 187.5, 45],
              [187.5, 187.5, 15]])

b = np.array([[262.5, 262.5, 45],
              [262.5, 262.5, 15],
              [3,3,5],
              [5,5,7],
              [8,8,9]])
```

I tried the code below, but the output is not what I want, can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? or is there any other way to do it?

```
out = [x[(x == b[:,None]).all(1).any(0)] for x in a]
```

The output I want is:

```
array[[262.5, 262.5, 45],
      [262.5, 262.5, 15]]
```

Comment: what do you mean for "identical element"? do you need to take the subset of vector that are the same in `a` and `b` matrices?

Comment: yes, in this case the identical elements are `[262.5, 262.5, 45]` and  `[262.5, 262.5, 15] `, if we view them as point or vector

Comment: ok. in this case check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a[np.all([np.isin(ai, b) for ai in  a], axis=1)]
```

or also:

```
b[np.all([np.isin(bi, a) for bi in  b], axis=1)]
```

Comment: Both lines are not equivalent. Moreover, this is totally wrong. It will return each row such that all elements of that row are **somewhere in the whole second array**. See with `a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` and `b=[[9, 8, 7],[5, 4, 6],[2, 3, 1]]` (nothing should be returned, but everything is returned).

Comment: I think that he is interested into take all equal vectors (intersection between `a` and `b`) independently on the position. Indeed if you notice `a` and `b` have different number of lines (vectors)

Comment: Still that is not what your code is doing, test with the arrays I gave. What you think you're doing is done with `np.array([ai for ai in a if np.any(np.all(ai == b, axis=-1))])`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to using `np` all the way (which I think is the case, seeing the list comprehension) - you can do a `set` intersection

```py
x = set(map(tuple, a)).intersection(set(map(tuple, b)))
print(x)
# {(262.5, 262.5, 15.0), (262.5, 262.5, 45.0)}
```

You can convert this back to a `np.ndarray` by

```
xarr = np.array(list(x)) 
print(xarr)
# array([[262.5, 262.5,  45. ],
#       [262.5, 262.5,  15. ]])
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear if you want the first contiguous block or not. Let assume not, and that you want to retrieve all rows of same index in both arrays and for which all elements are equal:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6],
    ]
)

b = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [5, 5, 5],
    ]
)

expected = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [5, 5, 5],
    ]
)
```

First method is using a for loop, but might not be efficient:

```py
out = np.array([x for x, y in zip(a, b) if np.all(x == y)])
assert np.all(out == expected)
```

Second method is vectorized and so much more efficient, you just need to crop your arrays beforehand because they don't have the same length (`zip` does that silently):

```py
num_rows = min(a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
a_ = a[:num_rows]
b_ = b[:num_rows]

rows_mask = np.all(a_ == b_, axis=-1)
out = a_[rows_mask, :]

assert np.all(out == expected)
```